# Manipulationg images

Tags: mesh

Only downloaded blender this week for the first time so still working out what its capable of.

One question I cant find the answer to is:

Can you add mesh to a 2D background image in order to make it 3d by moving vertexes in the z?

Many Thanks

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of the question specific to what you are asking and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can import the image as a simple 4-vertex plane with the **Import Images as Planes** addon. 
Then you can add a Subdivision Surface modifier & change the smoothing algorithm from **Catmull-Clark** to **Simple**, which will add more vertices but keep the same mesh shape.

Increase the resolution to get as many vertices as you need.